# crashing ntdll.dll in multithreaded win form app

Tags: c#, multithreading, multiprocessing, ntdll

Using **VS2013 64bit , .Net FW 4.5.0 , EMGU.CV, NReco.VideoConverter**

There are several project in the Solution. The workflow of the solution is:

1. Input a video file (any format)
2. Split the file in multiple files (in 5 mins duration)
3. Convert 2 video files at a time with **TPL**
4. And start Video Processing Parallely
5. After Processing two files parallelly (5 mins each), I have to close both of the processing window(winForm project actually)
6. Then the Convertion of next two splitted file started
7. After successful conversion, step 4 starts again and will Run until processes all the splited file.

**Here is the problem :**  It successfully comes to the 7th step and stop working after successful conversion of 2nd two files. Actually, while it attempted to restart the vedio processing. And the error is `VSHOST32.exe has stopped working`. End in event log I got this:

```
Faulting application name: ffmpegwrapperTest.vshost.exe, 
version: 12.0.21005.1, time stamp: 0x524fac11
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16384, 
time stamp: 0x5010ae7a
Exception code: 0xc0000374
```

What is wrong with `ntdll.dll?`

Comment: Look at the complete stack trace: you are probably calling a method incorrectly. With the stack trace you can see in which part of your code the error is triggered.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with ntdll.dll, it is doing its job.  It detected that a heap was corrupted and dutifully reports it.  Heap corruption is a standard failure mode of unmanaged code.  You are using a lot of it.  Fixing the underlying bug is, erm, character building.  But it probably has something to do with not locking properly, code in libraries is generally not thread-safe.